# In R create a waypoint to cross from Anadyr, Russia, into North America?

Tags: r

In R, I created a raster covering the world (without Antarctica) in ~60,000 points, and kept only points in a grid approximately 100km from their 4 closest neighbors. I further reduced the number of points to those on land, got the elevation for those points, and then I reduced the number of points to those whose elevation was <2000m and >0m. By the end, I have about 14,000 points.

```
library(raster) ##load package to create raster of points over entire world
library(sp)  ##load package for st_points, st_transform, st_buffer, and st_intersection functions 
library(rgdal) ##elevatr package dependency
library(elevatr) ##load package for get_elev_point function 

r <- raster(ncol = 360, nrow = 180, ymn = -55, ymx = 90) ## Remove Antarctica
points <- as.data.frame(rasterToPoints(r))
points.sf <- st_as_sf(points, coords = 1:2, crs = 4326) ## Convert points to sf object

## Create a bounding box for your points to set the extent for the grid
bbox <- st_bbox(points.sf) ##cannot use r, because will lose precision of Long/Lat after the decimal

## Define the desired spacing between grid points: ~ 100km
#You can convert this distance to degrees using the approximate conversion factor of 1 degree ≈ 111.32 km at the equator. 
grid_spacing_degrees <- 1

## Create a grid of points within the bounding box
x_values <- seq(from = bbox["xmin"], to = bbox["xmax"], by = grid_spacing_degrees)
y_values <- seq(from = bbox["ymax"], to = bbox["ymin"], by = -grid_spacing_degrees)

grid <- expand.grid(x = x_values, y = y_values)

## Convert the grid to an sf object:
grid.sf <- st_as_sf(grid, coords = 1:2, crs = 4326)

## Keep only the points on land
intersection <- st_intersection(grid.sf, world)
##took 2.5 hours

land.grid.points <- intersection

## Check that it worked
plot(st_geometry(world))
plot(land.grid.points, pch=20, cex = 0.00005, max.plot = 10)

## For points on land, get elevation
elevation.land.grid.points <- get_elev_point(land.grid.points, prj = "EPSG:4326", z = 6, src = "aws") #zoom 6 is ground resolution per zoom in km at a given latitude: 0° = 2446m; 45° = 1729.6m; 60° = 1223m; uses Amazon Web Services; elevation in meters
        
elev <- as.data.frame(elevation.land.grid.points)

elev.constrained <- elev[elev$elevation > 0 & elev$elevation < 2000, ] ## fewer than 30 points have elevation = 0m, so removing them as done here is not harmful to the overall number of points
##confirmed elevations < 0 were off the coast a bit and in water, so correct to remove elevations < 0
```

Next, I plan to set the raster values to be the elevation and define the length of an edge connection two vertices to be their great circle Vincenty Ellipsoid distance. Thus, I will have edges in the graph connecting vertices with great circle distances as edge lengths.

```
library(geosphere) ##load package for distVincentyEllipsoid function

# Create vertices with latitude, longitude, and elevation information
vertices <- data.frame(
  Lon = elev.constrained$coords.x1,
  Lat = elev.constrained$coords.x2,
  Elevation = elev.constrained$elevation
)
# Calculate great circle distances between vertices
distances <- distVincentyEllipsoid(vertices[, c("Lon", "Lat")], a = 6378137, b = 6356752.3142, f = 1/298.257223563) #meters

# Add edges to the graph using the full distance matrix
edge_weights <- as.vector(distances)
g <- add_edges(g, edges = combn(vertex_indices, 2), edge.attr = edge_weights)
```

Practically, I stopped here, because creating object `g` uses too much memory, and I am working on finding a way.

But once I get `g`, then I can continue to set the raster values to be the elevation, and restrict movement from one vertex to the 8 closest neighbors. In this way, the constraints for travel will incorporate both elevation and distance.

```
# Load your existing elevation raster
# use rasterize to create desired raster
r_data <- rasterize(x=elev.constrained[, 3:4], # lon-lat data
                    y=r, # raster object
                    field=elev.constrained[, 1], # vals to fill raster with
                    fun=mean) # aggregate function

# Create a new raster to store edge lengths (great circle distances)
edge_length_raster <- r_data

# Assign edge lengths to raster cells
values(edge_length_raster) <- distances

# You now have an elevation raster with edge lengths based on great circle distances

# plot(edge_length_raster) ##checkpoint
tr1 <- transition(edge_length_raster, transitionFunction = mean, directions = 8) ##uses Moore neighborhood

image(transitionMatrix(tr1))

h8 <- geoCorrection(tr1,  scl=FALSE)
```

Finally, I will find the shortest path from one location to another using Dijkstra's algorithm.

My issue is I need to cross continents sometimes over water, like from Anadyr, Russia, into North America. How do I code this? Do I go into my base grid and assign a point to the water in between, or do I somehow "connect" Anadyr, Russia, to a point on the other side of the Bering Strait in North America?

Comment: Are there restrictions on 'mode' of travel, i.e. no airplanes, no donkeys, only walking?

Comment: @Chris The simulation is humans walking across the landscape over thousands of years. So, no crossing oceans, no crossing mountain ranges. 'Thousands of years' means people would have taken different paths, and that's okay. I'm trying to create the common path (constrained by elevation and water) following great circle distances between points to account for the shape of the Earth and the "shortest path" via Dijkstra's algorithm. Because I said no crossing water, I am at a loss for how to have people cross from Russia over the Bering Strait into North America as they would over ice long ago.

Comment: `The simulation is humans walking across the landscape over thousands of years`, `elevation (…) >0m` — does that really make sense in this context? Shouldn’t the minimum elevation be lower?

Comment: Maybe you need a worldmap from 10,000 BCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is nice, but slightly flawed.

> The simulation is [that of] humans walking across the landscape over thousands of years. So, no crossing oceans, no crossing mountain ranges. [...] Because I said no crossing water, I am at a loss for how to have people cross from Russia over the Bering Strait into North America as they would over ice long ago.

The thing is -- thereby laying aside coastal resp. maritime migration theories -- that our planet's surface hasn't been static since humankind began to wander Earth. When the Paleo-Indians moved from Asia to America some 12000 to 20000 years ago, there was no [Bering Strait](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bering_Strait) but [Beringia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beringia), a land-bridge. Your model would have to reflect not only the existence of such landmasses -- Beringia was not the only one, see e.g. [Doggerland](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doggerland), and esp. [Sunda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sundaland) - [Wallacea](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallacea) - [Sahul](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sahul) -- but depending on the considered timespan also their dynamics, as illustrated in Fig.1.

[image: Beringia]

[**Fig.1:**](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/52/Beringia_land_bridge-noaagov.gif) Beringia sea levels (blues) and land elevations (browns) measured in metres from 21,000 years ago to present.

Therefore it might be more convenient to change the geodata basis, and switch to [paleogeographic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palaeogeography) maps, aka paleomaps. Except of corresponding packages for R -- at least [`rgplates`](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/rgplates/index.html), [`mapast`](https://github.com/macroecology/mapast) and [`velociraptr`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/velociraptr/versions/1.1.0) I'm aware of -- you might be interested in [Building Palaeogeographic Maps in R](https://bcmoon.uk/palaeontology/palaeomaps-in-R/). In case you're not bound to R, further paleomap software can be found.

*Edit:* As [simpson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14538020/simpson) considered in a comment below, one could at need also apply [`add_edges`](https://r.igraph.org/reference/add_edges.html), and related functions, from the [`igraph`](https://r.igraph.org/index.html) package to model the Earth's surface in detail, e.g. for hypothetical scenarios which can not be represented using paleo maps.

---

P.S.: Note, that not everything under mean sea level is also under water, e.g. the [Caspian Depression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caspian_Depression). The higher the resolution of your model, the more relevant that could become.

Comment: You are right. My goal is to compare some biological variation to distance from Africa (following human migration routes currently proposed) and potentially distance from a point A to point B. Due to the multiple waves of human migration, it does not seem possible to (is this what you were implying) create distances between points based on the makeup of the landmass at the "point" in time humans were expected to migrate through the area? 

What can you constructively add to my current approach Re: my question of connecting points across water? If you are comfortable.

Comment: Firstly, to avoid misunderstandings, I don't see a fundamental problem in Your *implementation* at all. Just an aspect in Your premise. Taking only into consideration a wandering over landmasses, and laying aside coastal resp. maritime migration theories, You have to take paleoenvironmental maps for the considered time span and add -- as You suggested in Your OP -- connective points where land has been, and remove points where at that time there was water masses -- rivers shouldn't be relevant obstacles.

Comment: Consider also further important wandering routes besides Beringia, e.g. Asia-Australia, or to Britan from (today's) continental Europe. And in some historical context, people expanded through excellent maritime knowledge like the Polynesians, so from some point in history the limitation on a land migration cannot hold anymore.

Comment: And given the code I provided as a sample, what do you suggest for the implementation? What code will forge the connection across water connecting landmasses?

Comment: I might have not expressed myself meticulously enough, causing perhaps confusion. In short -- what I wanted to say in the core is, that you need another geodata basis. Except of paleo map packages for R (at least `mapast` I'm aware of) you might be interested in [Building Palaeogeographic Maps in R](https://bcmoon.uk/palaeontology/palaeomaps-in-R/)

Comment: Updated the answer post correspondingly.

Comment: That does solve the problem of crossing the Bering Strait, because you have essentially removed the water by suggesting Paleo maps where that location held land. However, I am still looking for the R code to link two vertices across 'water' that I have previously excluded. How can I add an edge? Will ```igraph``` ```add_edge```work? I just have to identify the most distal vertex location in Siberia and in Alaska and then just ```add_edge``` to connect them?

Comment: That sounds good and should work.

Comment: Updated post correspondingly. It came to my mind, that one could handle that way e.g. hypothetical scenarios where paleo maps might not help (legendary landmasses like Atlantis, Hyperboreia or whatever ^^).