# R geosphere::distVincentyEllipsoid in batches for weighted edge lengths

Tags: r

I am trying to create a graph with vertices and edges with weights as great circle distances.

To create my data from scratch, refer to this [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77086430/in-r-create-a-waypoint-to-cross-from-anadyr-russia-into-north-america).

Otherwise, here are 16 vertices out of 14,316 of my data:

```
Lon <- c(179.5,  31.5,  32.5,  33.5,  34.5,  30.5,  31.5,  32.5,  33.5,  34.5,  31.5,  32.5,  33.5,  34.5,  35.5,  36.5)
Lat <- c(-16.402778,  -1.402778,  -1.402778,  -1.402778,  -1.402778,  -2.402778,  -2.402778,  -2.402778,  -2.402778,  -2.402778, -3.402778,  -3.402778,  -3.402778,  -3.402778,  -3.402778,  -3.402778)
Elevation <- c(99, 1194, 1134, 1134, 1358, 1425, 1307, 1135, 1134, 1452, 1206, 1199, 1194, 1357, 1478, 1333)
vertices <- data.frame(Lon, Lat, Elevation)
> vertices
     Lon        Lat Elevation
1  179.5 -16.402778        99
2   31.5  -1.402778      1194
3   32.5  -1.402778      1134
4   33.5  -1.402778      1134
5   34.5  -1.402778      1358
6   30.5  -2.402778      1425
7   31.5  -2.402778      1307
8   32.5  -2.402778      1135
9   33.5  -2.402778      1134
10  34.5  -2.402778      1452
11  31.5  -3.402778      1206
12  32.5  -3.402778      1199
13  33.5  -3.402778      1194
14  34.5  -3.402778      1357
15  35.5  -3.402778      1478
16  36.5  -3.402778      1333
```

First, I define a graph where each vertex represents a location on the Earth's surface specified by latitude and longitude decimal coordinates. Second, I connect the vertices with edges, where each edge represents a possible path between two locations. And for each edge in the graph, I calculate the weight (cost) of the edge using the Vincenty Ellipsoid distance formula to find the great circle distance between the two locations represented by the connected vertices.

```
library(igraph)
library(geosphere)

# Create an empty graph
g <- graph.empty()

# Define the batch size (adjust as needed)
batch_size <- 4

# Calculate the total number of batches
num_batches <- ceiling(nrow(vertices) / batch_size)

# Function to calculate great circle distances
calculate_distances <- function(vertices1, vertices2) {
  # Extract the Lon and Lat columns for each set of vertices
  coords1 <- vertices1[, c("Lon", "Lat")]
  coords2 <- vertices2[, c("Lon", "Lat")]
  
  # Convert coordinates to a matrix with numeric values
  coords1 <- as.matrix(coords1)
  coords2 <- as.matrix(coords2)
  
  # Calculate distances using distVincentyEllipsoid
  distances <- distVincentyEllipsoid(coords1, coords2,
                                     a = 6378137, b = 6356752.3142, f = 1/298.257223563)
  
  return(distances)
}
```

Because my real data are 14,316 rows, trying to create `g` (below) without a batch approach produces the error `Error: cannot allocate vector of size 21858.7 Gb`.

So, here is the approach to break vertices up into batches, but it is not successful to you have edges in the graph connecting vertices with great circle distances as edge lengths.

```
# Iterate through batches
for (i in 1:num_batches) {
  # Determine the start and end indices for the current batch
  start_index <- (i - 1) * batch_size + 1
  end_index <- min(i * batch_size, nrow(vertices))
  
  # Subset the vertices for the current batch
  batch_vertices <- vertices[start_index:end_index, c("Lon", "Lat")]
  
  # Add vertices to the existing graph and get their indices
  batch_vertex_indices <- add.vertices(g, nv = nrow(batch_vertices))
  
  # Calculate great circle distances for the current batch
  batch_distances <- calculate_distances(batch_vertices, vertices)
  
  # Generate combinations of vertex pairs within the current batch
  edge_combinations <- combn(batch_vertex_indices, 2)
  
  # Ensure edge combinations and weights match correctly
  num_edges <- ncol(edge_combinations)
  num_weights <- length(batch_distances)
  
  # Adjust the number of weights to match the number of edges
  adjusted_weights <- rep(batch_distances, each = num_edges)
  
  # Trim excess weights if necessary
  adjusted_weights <- adjusted_weights[1:num_edges]
  
  # Add edges to the existing graph with edge distances
  g <- add_edges(g, edges = edge_combinations, edge.attr = adjusted_weights)
}
```

Returns the error: `Error in out[, i] <- r :  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length`.

For a while it seemed like the `calculate_distances()` function was the problem. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to calculate the distances between all 14,000 points? That is over 100 million distances.

Comment: You write to files, certainly with `terra::rast` (exploring this with terra::vect), and `textConnection(` [write igraph to file 'a' append](https://github.com/igraph/rigraph/issues/544) and experiment with batch sizes to memory load...using `htop` or Mac/Windows equivalent to see batch size where session crashes.

Comment: Perhaps `sample(vertices, some_reasonable#, replace = TRUE)` and see if the graph signal seems stable-ish across samples to address @Dave2e. What's the min/max of Elevation?

Comment: @Dave2e Yes, that does sound crazy to calculate the pairwise distances for 14,000 points. I am basing my methods based on the Supplementary Materials of a paper [Geography predicts neutral genetic diversity of human populations](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1800886/#) I believe used ArcGIS. So, doing it in R 20 years later is very different, so I am working through how to reproduce this method.

Comment: @Chris The min I set as the elevation is 0m, and the max I set at elevation is 1999m (less than 2000m) for the ease of a person walking.